# Conceptual problem regarding the "intrinsic" energy level for a PN junction

Tags: energy, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

As I understand, ***intrinsic*** silicon, as opposed to extrinsic, means undoped silicon that has ***no*** added donors or acceptors. The diagram bellow, taken from the book *The PN Junction Diode* (George W. Neudeck), represents the energy band diagram for a p-n junncton

[image]

and as we can see $E_i$, the intrinsic energy level, is represented by the dotted line. How can we talk about an "intrinsic" energy level in a ***doped*** material that has a p-type material on one side and n-type on the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intrinsic level is the energy the Fermi level would sit at *if the material were intrinsic*. It doesn't require the material to be intrinsic to make sense, the same is true for the intrinsic carrier concentration $n_i$. The offset of the Fermi level from the intrinsic level (in a uniform material) is an indicator of doping level: $E_F - E_i > 0$ for n-type doping and $E_F - E_i < 0$ for p-type.

Comment: But the Fermi level can't be bent like $E_i$ is above, since $E_F$ is a constant (under equilibrium conditions), so $E_F$ can't really take the place of $E_i$. Besides, I can't really see what is meant by "if the material were intrinsic", if the material were intrinsic, we would be dealing with a completely different problem, wouldn't we?

Comment: You don't have to draw the intrinsic level if you don't want to. It is a useful reference energy level to have in a band diagram because the deviation of (quasi-)Fermi levels from the intrinsic level allows you to see how much electron and hole concentrations differ from intrinsic. In the pn-junction diagram, the $E_F$ and $E_i$ crossover indicates the point at which $n=p=n_i$, for instance. The fact that $E_i$ can bend unlike $E_F$ isn't relevant because $E_i$ isn't the actual Fermi level.